# padding and attention mask does not work as intended in batch input in GPT language model

Tags: python, pytorch, language-model, huggingface-transformers

The following code is without batch:

```
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
import torch

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model.eval()
context=torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode("This is")])
output, past = model(context)
token = torch.argmax(output[..., -1, :])
print(tokenizer.decode(token.item()))

output: ' a'
```

This is working fine. Now, I extended this to batch setting:

```
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
import torch

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model.eval()

context=[torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("This is ")),torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello How are "))]
context=pad_sequence(context,batch_first=True)

mask=torch.tensor([[1,1,0],[1,1,1]])
output, past = model(context,attention_mask=mask)
token = torch.argmax(output[..., -1, :],dim=1)
tokenizer.decode(token)

output: '\n you'
```

Here `\n` is next token for the first context and `you` is next token for second context of the batch.
But The expected next token for the first context is `a`, since all the settings are same. Furthermore, if you reduce the second context to 2 token you will get `a` in this batch setting. So clearly, model can not understand the padding.
Also, the attention mask does not work. Because,
after padding the next token of sequence `this is` is 0 (zero). And according to the attention mask (`[1,1,0]`), this zero should be avoided and only the tokens `this` and `is` should be attended. The proofs that this attention masking is not working are:

- Use attention mask [1,1,1], that means attend even on the padding zero, you get the same output
  which is `\n`.
- Use the the string `this is!`. Here `!` has the zero index in the vocabulary matrix. Again you get the same output which is `\n`.

Only time, it is possible to get desirable output is without the batch settings and attention mask ( now it seems, it does not matter because it has no effect anyway)

Then I found [this](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.pad_token), which suggested to use pad_token. So I used like following:

```
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
import torch
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence  

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2",pad_token="<PAD>")
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model.eval()

context=[torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("This is <PAD> ")),torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello How are"))]
context=torch.stack(context)
print(context)
mask=torch.tensor([[1,1,0],[1,1,1]])

output, past = model(context,attention_mask=mask)
token = torch.argmax(output[..., -1, :],dim=1)
tokenizer.decode(token)

output: 'The you'
```

Here `The` is next token for the first context and `you` is next token for second context of the batch. This is also not working. Because `The` is not expected for the first context.

How do I use variable length sequence in batch setting in gpt/gpt2 model?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but you don't need to implement you own attention masking and padding. The Transformers library provides the [encode_plus()](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode_plus) and [batch_encode_plus()](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.batch_encode_plus) functions that will perform tokenization, generate the attention masks, and do padding for you. The results come out as Python dictionaries.